# How to use the POI to cancel the automatic adjustment of the spacing between Chinese and western languages in word paragraphs

Tags: java, apache-poi

I use `XWPFDocument` and `XWPFParagraph` class to create a Word, But there is always a gap between Chinese and Western, I cancel the automatic adjustment of the spacing between Chinese and western languages in word paragraphs through WORD can solve the problem, but how can I do that useing code;

I think can use `CTStyle`, but I don't know how to do that;

```
XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument();
XWPFParagraph page = doc.createParagraph();
XWPFRun runs = page.createRun();
runs.setBold(false);
runs.setFontFamily("宋体");
runs.setFontSize(9);
runs.setText("12H型");

//export
OutputStream output = response.getOutputStream();
BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutPut = new BufferedOutputStream(output);
bufferedOutPut.flush();
doc.write(bufferedOutPut);
bufferedOutPut.close();
```

Comment: problem like 12H 型, but I want 12型。no space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you mean the settings described in [Configure text spacing between East Asian and Latin text](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/adjust-text-spacing-and-line-breaks-in-form-templates-that-contain-both-east-asian-and-latin-text-4f6d3705-6197-4e8f-b106-83b6eca91cd5#bm3).

Those settings are stored in `document.xml` using the elements `autoSpaceDE`and `autoSpaceDN` in paragraph properties.

Using `apache poi` this could be done like so:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

public class CreateWordEnglishAndChinese {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();

  XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  if (paragraph.getCTP().getPPr() == null) paragraph.getCTP().addNewPPr();
  if (paragraph.getCTP().getPPr().getAutoSpaceDE() == null) paragraph.getCTP().getPPr().addNewAutoSpaceDE();
  paragraph.getCTP().getPPr().getAutoSpaceDE().setVal(org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STOnOff.OFF);
  if (paragraph.getCTP().getPPr().getAutoSpaceDN() == null) paragraph.getCTP().getPPr().addNewAutoSpaceDN();
  paragraph.getCTP().getPPr().getAutoSpaceDN().setVal(org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STOnOff.OFF);

  XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();
  run.setText("12H型:Type 12H");

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("CreateWordEnglishAndChinese.docx");
  document.write(out);
  out.close();
  document.close();

 }
}
```

Comment: yeah, I solved this problem with your method. thank you very much.